# @Transactional not rolling back with RuntimeException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I am creating simple spring boot application. I used spring transaction management to handle the transaction. Here is my code.

ServiceImpl class

```
@Service("orderService")
public class OrderServiceImpl implements OrderService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Autowired
    private OrderDao orderDao;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    @Override
    public Long placeOrder(OrderPlacementRequest request) {
      customerDao.save(request.getCustomer());
      return orderDao.placeOrder(request.getOrder());
    }
 }
```

OrderDaoImpl class,

```
@Repository("orderDao")
public class OrderDaoImpl extends AbstractHibernateDao implements OrderDao        {

    @Override
    public Long placeOrder(Order order) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Test Error Message");
    }
}
```

Configuration class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

 //Other Configurations

     @Autowired
     private final Environment environment;

     @Bean
     public DataSource dataSource() {
         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
   dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

OrderController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/place", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Long placeOrder(@RequestBody OrderPlacementRequest request) {
        return orderService.placeOrder(request);
    }
}
```

In my case even though second method `placeOrder` failed. Customer will be saved in mysql database. What I wanted is to rollback the customer saving method. I went through few articles on transaction management including spring docs and stackoverflow. Still can not find the problem.

Updated with Controller class.

Comment: Do you call `OrderServiceImpl.placeOrder()` from other `OrderServiceImpl` methods?

Comment: @Ivan No. It will call from the OrderController class.

Comment: In `transactionManager` bean definition, line `transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());`, is `dataSource()` a bean? If so, try injecting it and calling it directly.

Comment: You're using a DataSourceTransactionManager to handle Hibernate Transactions. That won't work. Use Spring-data-jpa *as documented* (i.e. use the starter, let Spring create the DataSource, TransactionManager, and use the power of Spring-data-jpa to define your DAOs).

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your comment. Now it works fine. Cheers !!!